# SQL Oracle - сортировка данных по первому вхождению символа-разделителя

Tags: sql, oracle, сортировка

Помогите пожалуйста.

Имеются данные, которые заносят в таблицу. Самый главный столбец, по которому необходимо реализовать сортировку - № чертежа.
Чертеж может быть записан по разному (начинаться с цифр или начинаться с букв, в основном, если начинается с букв, то название состоит из двух основных частей и разделяется каким-то символом - точкой, тире, пробелом, слешем) например:

> СК-123, СК-124, С-1234, М-123-123, К.12, ЭСКИЗ 1234, 234567.23 и т.д.

Необходимо каким-то образом отделить первую часть в № чертежа, то есть ту, что находится слева до первого вхождения одного из символов и сделать сортировку по алфавиту сначало по ней, а затем по второй части уже по дате добавления в таблицу.

Попробую привести пример как данные вносят в таблицу и что должно получиться на выходе. Допустим, данные внесли в таком порядке: 
СК-123, 
СК-123,
СК-122, 
СК-120,
М-11111, 
М-22222,
ЭСКИЗ.123,
654321.123456,
123456.654321 
Что мне надо на выходе: 
123456.654321, 
654321.123456,
М-11111,
М-22222, 
СК-123,
СК-123,
СК-122,
СК-120,
ЭСКИЗ.123

То есть получается, по левой части чертежа (то что слева от первого разделителя) данные сначала сортируются по алфавиту, затем сортировка идет по правой части по дате добавления.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если вы сузите диалект SQL до конкретной базы данных - получите больше ответов. Ситуация не совсем типичная - данные не нормализованы, нужно хитрить и использовать нестандартные средства, а они разнятся от СУБД к СУБД.

Comment: `patindex('%[., -]%',строка)` судя по описанию в интернете даст позицию одного из перечисленных символов. по ней уже делать substring. проверить сейчас нет возможности

Comment: Так у вас Oracle или SQL Server? В заголовке появился Oracle, но ранее вы указали в метках SQL Server...

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT S,
  SUBSTRING(S, 1, C-1)left_part,
  SUBSTRING(S, C+1, LEN(S))right_part
FROM(
  SELECT S, PATINDEX('%[. -]%', S+'.')C
  FROM(VALUES('qwe 1'),('qweqwe.2-2'),('qeewq-3'),('qweqwe'))S(S)
)T

/*результат:

S            left_part    right_part
qwe 1        qwe          1
qweqwe.2-2   qweqwe       2-2
qeewq-3      qeewq        3
qweqwe       qweqwe 
*/
```

Обратите внимание, что в паттерне дефис стоит в конце.

Если написать так: "%[ -.]%" - это будет означать диапазон символов от " " до ".".